# Rails: locations for globals & ENV variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, automated-tests, global-variables

We've been asked to "thaw" a year-old project and I'm trying to at least get all tests passing.

Project has a dependency on a 3rd-party service, call it 'transmogrifier'. In `config/uploader.yml` the api_key is set:

```
:default:
  api_key: "<%= ENV['TRANSMOGRIFIER_API_KEY'] %>"
test:
  api_key: 'fake_transmogrifier_api_key'
```

works in production and dev (because it's set in shell's `ENV`) but it's not being set in `test` env. There's no other mention of 'fake_transmogrifier_api_key' in the codebase. Where might previous developers have set this value? Best practice?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In testing we don't hit external API's, instead we Stub the requests in `spec_helper.rb` using `Webmock` gem.

You can refer the following link for more clarification
[stub external service requests](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests)

Hope it helps.